# Calculate $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)}$ in use of disturbance of sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation

I need calculate
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)}$$
in use of disturbance of sum method:
$$\boxed{\boxed{\sum_{k=m}^Ma_k+a_{M+1}=a_m+\sum_{k=m+1}^Ma_{k+1}}}
 $$

### My try

I know how to solve this task in "traditional" way but I am trying to do it with that method:
$$S_n=S_n$$
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)}  $$

ok - now I want to have the same piece as on the left side of equal. So i decide to use:
$$  i' = i+1 $$
$$ \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)} = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} $$
but there I divide by 0... 
How to avoid that problem?

### Method

I don't know if the name "disturbance of sum" is correct in english so I am going to give example of another task with this approach:
$$ S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}q^k = ? $$
$$ S_n+q^{n+1}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}q^k=1+\sum_{k=0}^{n}q^{k+1}= 1+q\sum_{k=0}^{n}q^{k}=1+qS_n
$$
$$(q-1)S_n=q^{n+1}-1
$$

$$ S_n=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}
$$

Comment: What's the $S_n = S_n$ method?

Comment: disturbance of sum - I don't know if it is corrent name of that in english - The method is about take the first and last element from the sum and find common factor for them

Comment: What is the name in your language?

Comment: I gave example to the post

Comment: If I understand you want to work this out by working on the index. That works if you use partial fractions and then replace the index for one of the sums, but this amounts to the same thing as normal telescoping series method that you said you knew (instead of writing out, we keep everything in the sums).

Comment: The method you are describing as "disturbance of sum" is more typically referred to as a **perturbation method** in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telescoping is a method where we try to write $a_{k}$ on the form $a_k = b_{k+1} - b_k$ for some sequence $b_k$. From this form the sum of the series follows directly as $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k = b_{n+1} - b_0$.

What you are trying to do, from looking at your example, looks like the opposite of telescoping: to try to write $a_k$ on a form like $a_{k+1} - qa_k = b_k$ where $q$ is some constant (this can be generalized, but let's stick with the simplest case here). If you are able to do so and where $b_k$ is 'easier' than $a_k$ so that you are able to sum $b_k$ then by summing the recurrence relation you would be able to find the sum of $a_k$ as

$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_{k} = \frac{a_0 - a_{n+1} + \sum_{k=0}^n b_k}{1-q}$$

However, don't expect all methods to work with all series. Just as telescoping, this approach would only work in some special cases. Being good at finding sums is to figure out what methods works best with what series. For the series in question telescoping is definitely the way to go and the latter method would not work as $b_k$ would be an even more complicated series than that of $a_k$ so you should just discard this method for the given series.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the intended use of the provided identity $$\sum_{k=m}^M a_k + a_{M+1} = a_m + \sum_{k=m}^M a_{k+1}$$ is **not** by assigning $$a_k = \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)},$$ but rather, $$\boxed{\boxed{a_k = \frac{1}{k+1}}}.$$  When you do this, you immediately obtain (for $m = 0$ and $M = n-1$) $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{n} = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+2}.$$  Upon rearrangement, we get $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2} = 1 - \frac{1}{n},$$ and since $$\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2} = \frac{(k+2) - (k+1)}{(k+1)(k+2)} = \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)},$$ this concludes the proof.

Another way to see this is to rewrite the perturbation identity in the form $$\sum_{k=m}^M (a_k - a_{k+1}) = a_m - a_{M+1}.$$

Comment: why $a_k = \frac{1}{k+1}$? Our $a_k$ is $\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}$

Comment: @VirtualUser And where in your question does it explicitly state to choose $a_k = 1/((k+1)(k+2))$?  Your choice of $a_k$ does not lead to a solution, and even if it did, it would not lead to a simpler solution than the choice I have illustrated.  The whole point of the question is to show you that **the identity that you are told to use is a telescoping identity**.